# type lost when using java8 stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

code first:

```
    net.sf.json.JSONArray ja = new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        net.sf.json.JSONObject obj = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
        obj.put("number", "k"+i);
        ja.add(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(ja.stream().map(s->((net.sf.json.JSONObject)s).getString("number")).peek(s->System.out.println(s.getClass())).collect(Collectors.joining(";")));
```

as you can see, I try to get a `String` of `JSONObject` and join them. And it works above like this:

```
    class java.lang.String
    class java.lang.String
    class java.lang.String
    k0;k1;k2
```

However `ja.stream().map(s->((JSONObject)s).getString("number"))` seems return not a `Stream<String>` but `Stream<Object>` which I couldn't append `String` intermidiate operation like `.map(s->s.substring(3))`. In other words, type lost.

So can anybody give any advice?

Comment: `JSONArray` implements raw types. It'll poison your whole stream. Use a generic `List` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking down your stream statement does result in:

```
net.sf.json.JSONArray ja = new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
Stream stream1 = ja.stream();
Stream stream2 = stream1.map(s -> ((JSONObject) s).getString("number"));
```

As you can see, `stream1` is not of a generic type. Hence any transformations will not produce a generic type out of a non generic type. Changing either variable `ja` or variable `stream1` to a generic type will result in a `Stream<String>` for variable `stream2`:

```
net.sf.json.JSONArray ja = new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
Stream<Object> stream1 = ja.stream();
Stream<String> stream2 = stream1.map(s -> ((JSONObject) s).getString("number"));
```

Hence if you want to preserve type information you need a generic type which may carry it.